# Why don’t Sheretzs made into a Streimel convey tumah?

Tags: clothing, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, non-kosher-species, parashat-shemini, black-hats

The body of a sheretz conveys impurity. The translations of the animals that count as Sheratzim (listed in Parashat Shemini) often include weasels or ferrets as well as rats, insects, and lizards.

Streimels (and fur coats) are often made from furry weasel like animals (martens, ferrets, raccoons, muskrats).

Why don't the wearers of these furs and pelts become impure from handling the bodies of sheratzim? Does it matter if the hat still has the animals' head attached?

Comment: They don't have to be made with real animals

Comment: Why do you think they don't become impure from that?

Comment: The original title almost got my close vote as being off-season PTIJ, and it didn’t seem to accurately reflect the question. Can you confirm that my edit is in line with your intention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once a hide is tanned, even a bit, it no longer conveys impurity (Chullin 9:2).

Comment: (The exception _miderabanan_ is human skin.)

Comment: This addresses the question if shtreimlach are made of tanned hide. Are they?

Comment: @msh I have no proof, but I suspect they are tanned at least "a bit".

Comment: Doesn't that mishna imply that even before tanning, weasel skin is not *tameh*?

Comment: @Loewian I'm not sure what a weasel is in biblical hebrew or what is actually used in these hats, but yes it is certainly possible that the hides of some species aren't impure to begin with. This answer suffices with the broader but weaker claim that all hides (except human) once tanned a bit are pure.

Comment: Does that work according to the Rambam or does it have to be afatzim like with stam?  (Probably anyway most people who wear them are Ashkenazim who rely on RT.)

Comment: @Heshy it's an excellent question, I'd guess it depends if parchment is matza or diftera, but I know others have analyzed this question more carefully than I since indeed conceptually it could be a great counterexample to RT.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Chullin 9:1-9:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin.9?lang=bi), the removed hides of these animals do not convey *tumah*.  And, as noted by @doubleAA, even those species whose hides are impure are no longer impure once processed.  This is codified by Maimonides [*Hilchoth Shaar Avoth Hatumoth* 4:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Other_Sources_of_Defilement.4.8?lang=bi&with=Chullin&lang2=he):

> וְעוֹר הַחלֶד וְהָעַכְבָּר וְהַצָּב וְהַתִּנְשֶׁמֶת טָהוֹר אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא לַח וַעֲדַיִן לֹא עִבְּדוֹ וְלֹא הָלַךְ בּוֹ. אֲבָל עוֹר הָאֲנָקָה וְהַכֹּחַ וְהַלְּטָאָה וְהַחֹמֶט כִּבְשָׂרָן וּמְטַמֵּא בְּכַעֲדָשָׁה. וְאִם עִבְּדָן אוֹ שֶׁהִלֵּךְ בָּהֶן כְּדֵי עֲבוֹדָה טְהוֹרִין.
>
> And the skin of the "*choled*" (rat, weasel, mole rat, or mongoose), of
> the mouse, of the "*tzav*" (toad or spiny-tailed lizard), and of the
> "*tinshemeth*" (mole rat, gecko, chameleon, or monitor) are pure even
> when still moist and not yet tanned nor trodden upon. However, the
> skin of the "*anakah*" (gecko, hedgehog, or glass lizard), of the
> "koach" (dragon lizard, monitor, or chameleon), of the "*letaah*" (wall lizard or gecko), and of the "*chomet*" (slug, snail, or skink)
> are like their flesh and a lentil-sized portion of it imparts
> impurity. And if they were tanned, or trodden upon till tanned, they
> are pure.

[image: reptile skin hat]

tahor

Comment: Isn't this specifically subject to dispute in that mishna? Tanna Kamma holds עוֹר הָאֲנָקָה וְהַכֹּחַ וְהַלְּטָאָה וְהַחֹמֶט is impure like its flesh

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not aware of anyone who identifies any of those species with ones used for streimlach (sounds uncomfortable even in winter;) See eg https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9D#%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93